# Create a forum in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, site

Is there anyway to create an open source forum like Stack Overflow (question and answer site) in SharePoint without code(OOTB).

Comment: sharepoint version?

Comment: Version: 2010 or 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with discussion board site to share information and discuss topics with other people.The next following steps will show you how to create discussion board.

Login to your SharePoint site as the administrative account.
From the Site Actions , select  View All Site Content.
Click Create.
Click Discussion Board , type the name, click Create .
More information check also below article

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-discussion-board-HA010086728.aspx

There are some commercial forum products also available which can greatly enhance the user experience.

http://www.lightningtools.com/sharepoint-community-tools.aspx

Or you can also try:

http://spforums.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

OOTB there is nothing like this forum.

The farthest you can get is the community template in SP 2013 (writing your sharepoint version is key to have other people helping you otherwise our comments are meaningless).

The community template (of which the Discussion board list is the no-frills version) is a common message board, with moderation features, badge assignment (manual, not automatic) and 5 fixed level of seniority.

You can apply categories to posts but not multiple categories (as it happens with blog posts) which is a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a template called "Community Site" that is a dedicated site that works with discussion boards and seems to be the closest thing to a forum in SharePoint. Create a test site and give it a try.

Here are some links on the topic.

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/07/30/what-is-a-sharepoint-2013-community-site-aspx/

https://www.computerworld.com/article/2223802/microsoft-subnet/10-key-things-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-2013-community-sites.html